# Plot distance between couple of points in two different series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just plotted two series and I would like, for each values on x-axis, connect them with a line and write their distance (that I've alredy computed). I'm struggling already just for plotting the line: without

```
plt.plot([result[0][:no_obs], result[1][:no_obs]], 'ro-')
```

in the code the result is as the first picture. While, with it the result is as the second picture.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, header=None)
no_obs = len(df[0]);
rho1 = 0.2
rho2 = 0.4

plt.plot(result[0][:no_obs], 'go')
plt.plot(result[1][:no_obs], 'b*')
plt.plot([result[0][:no_obs], result[1][:no_obs]], 'ro-')

plt.title("rho1=%s - rho2=%s" % (str(rho1), str(rho2)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

## UPDATE

This is my dataset (y-values)

[image]

Comment: You need to become clear about which quantity you want to plot on the x and which on the y axis in each case, then use `plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest actually, x-axis is the index of my two arrays. I calculated the distance manually and so I don't have such a couple of valye (x, y)

Comment: That's what I'm saying. **Every** (cartesian 2D) plot has x and y, and you need to become clear about which quantity you want to use in that case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 
X is array of values [1,100]
Y is array of the values plotted

Comment: Please, an image of numbers is not helpful. Put them as text, at least, so people can copy-paste them if needed

Comment: Yes, so apparently you don't want x to be the "array of values [1,100]". In that case choose a different array, which corresponds to the values you want to see.